# google.cloud.storage.Client in Spyder doesn't work while it works in Powercell

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, gcloud, gsutil

after some [basic Google Authentication setup](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-python), I am now able to run below code by a simple comman line >`python temp001.py` in Powercell of Windows 10, which list my google buckets in cloud. I tried to run the same code by Spyder, but it doesn't work. May I ask why?

```
def implicit():
    from google.cloud import storage
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)
    return 1

a=implicit()
```

What I got in Spyder is `ContextualVersionConflict: (google-api-core 0.1.4 (c:\users\H42\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.6.0'), {'google-cloud-storage'})`.

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.6.3.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the message is telling you to update `google-api-core` to a version equal or greater than `1.6.0`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But no matter I tried `pip install --upgrade google-api-core` or  `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`, I got `Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade`. What should I do for that?